# AWK: How can I print averages of consecutive numbers in a file, but skip over alphabetical characters/strings?

Tags: awk, text-processing

I've figured out how to get the average of a file that contains numbers in all lines such as:

**Numbers.txt**

```
1

2

4

8
```

**Output:**

```
Average: 3.75
```

This is the code I use for that:

```
awk '{ sum += $1; tot++ } END { print sum / tot; }' Numbers.txt
```

However, the problem is that this doesn't take into account possible strings that might be in the file. For example, a file that looks like this:

**NumbersAndExtras.txt**

```
1

2

4

8

Hello

4

5

6

Cat

Dog

2

4

3
```

For such a file I'd want to print the multiple averages of the consecutive numbers, ignoring the strings such that the result looks something like this:

Output:

```
Average: 3.75

Average: 5

Average: 3
```

I could devise some complicated code that might accomplish that with variables and 'if' statements and loops and whatnot, but I've been told it's easier than that given some of awk features. I'd like to know how that might look like, along with an explanation of why it works.

Comment: Is blank line in your input existed?

Comment: I didn't take blank lines into account, only strings, but I suppose I should also seek that of course

Answer (score 0):

BEGIN runs before reading the first line from file. Set sum and count to 0.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ sum=0; count=0} {if ( /[a-z][A-Z]/ )  { if (count > 0) {avg = sum/count; print avg;} count=0; sum=0} else { count++; sum += $1} } END{if (count > 0) {avg = sum/count; print avg}} ' NumbersAndExtras.txt
```

When there is an alphabet on the line, calculate and print average so far.

And do the same in the END block that runs after processing the whole file.

Comment: This is something like what I was doing, and was told as mentioned, that if I took advantage of some of awk's features it might be simpler. Is this what you believe to be the simplest code to do it?

Comment: This is the simplest I could come up with so far. I am sure there are awk experts out there who can come up with simpler and more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Note: The value of this answer in *explaining* the solution; other answers offer *more concise* alternatives.

---

Try the following:

<sup>Note that this is an `awk` *command* with a script specified as a *multi-line shell string literal* - you can paste the whole thing into your terminal to try it; while it is possible to cram this into a single line, it hurts readability and the ability to comment:</sup>

```sh
awk '

 # Define output function that prints an average.
 function printAvg() { print "Average: ", sum/count }

 # Skip blank lines
 NF == 0 { next}    

 # Is the line non-numeric?
 /[[:alpha:]]/ { 
    # If this line ends a numeric block, print its
    # average now and reset the variables to start the next group.
    if (count) {
      printAvg()
      wasNum = sum = count = 0
    }
    # Skip to next line.
    next
  }

  # Numeric line: set flag, sum, and increment counter.
  { sum += $1; count++ }

  # Finally:
  END {
    # If there is a group whose average has not been printed yet,
    # do it now.
    if (count) printAvg()
  }

' NumbersAndExtras.txt
```

If we condense whitespace and strip the comments, we still get a reasonably readable solution, as long as we still use multiple lines:

```
awk '
 function printAvg() { print "Average: ", sum/count }
 NF == 0 { next}    
 /[[:alpha:]]/ { if (count) { printAvg(); sum = count = 0 } next }
 { sum += $1; count++ }
 END { if (count) printAvg() }
' NumbersAndExtras.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
$ awk '
  function avg(s, c) { print "Average: ", s/c }
  NF && !/^[[:digit:]]/ { if (count) avg(sum, count); sum = 0; count = 0; next}
  NF { sum += $1; count++ }
  END {if (count) avg(sum, count)}
' <file
```

Comment: You're not handling consecutive non-number lines correctly, so your last average will be `2.25`, not `3`. Truthfully, however, if you fix that, you'll end up having recreated my answer.

Comment: @mklement0: my bad, missing condition. Not yet, mine do not use extra waNum var.

Comment: True, that's an optimization worth making, but note that _generally_ (it doesn't matter for the sample data) it's more robust to use `if (count)` as a condition, as you could have numeric blocks containing only `0` lines or even blocks involving negative numbers so that `sum` ends up `0`, which would cause you to skip averages.

Comment: @mklement0: that's a worth note, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it *simple*:

```
awk '/^$/{next}
     /^[0-9]+/{a+=$1+0;c++;next}
     c&&a{print "Average: "a/c;a=c=0}
     END{if(c&&a){print "Average: "a/c}}' input_file
```

Results:

```
Average: 3.75
Average: 5
Average: 3
```